# Eclipse CDT - how to get multiple "Type Hierarchy" views

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to "pin" a **Type Hierarchy** view like with **Search** view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.

You're welcome to file an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) in Eclipse CDT's issue tracker.